# VSCode shows too much redundant class definitions for ActionController::Base in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, visual-studio-code

I am studying RoR Getting Started Guide and use VSCode. In test project RoR scaffolds following class:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
```

When in order to check definitions I press F12 over the `Base` word in this class VSCode provides over 50 suggestions like: `class Reline::KeyActor::Base` from
`reline-0.3.5/lib/reline/key_actor/base.rb` which is too far from expected class from `actionpack-7.0.5/lib/action_controller/base.rb`.

Is it expected behavior or I missed something in the configuration? I have following Ruby related extensions installed: Ruby; VSCode Ruby; Ruby Solargraph; ruby-rubocop; Ruby on Rails; ruby-symbols; ruby-linter. Language server is enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is normal behavior with VSCode and Ruby. Your best bet is to use the [Solargraph plugin](https://github.com/castwide/vscode-solargraph).